# More series help, this time a telescopic sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{2}{n^2 - 1}.$$ 
I Tried setting it up as a telescoping sum as $$\frac{2}{n} - \frac{2}{n-1}.$$ but now i'm sure that cannot be correct. Mayhaps I need to complete the square? or pull out an N? I'm sorry for asking so many questions. I just really need to get a grasp on these sort of things...

Comment: Also how do I format the question correctly? i can't make heads or tails of the help section.

Comment: Are you familiar with partial fraction decomposition and Telescoping Sums?

Comment: I am with telescoping sums, i just don't know how to properly decompose it. i'm trying to format the question right now to look better

Comment: haha! well if i can master the formatting on here surely i can master the problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know
$$
\frac{2}{n^2-1} = \frac{2}{(n-1)(n+1)} = \frac{A}{n-1} + \frac{B}{n+1}
$$
for some $A,B$. Solving for $A,B$ we find $A=1,B=-1$. Thus we want to calculate
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n+1})
$$
which telescopes. All the terms cancel except for $\frac{1}{2-1}$ and $\frac{1}{3-1}$ so the sum is $\frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: OF COURSE ARG Factoring always gets me. All that no child left behind BS made my Algebra Skills Weak
Thank you Very much!

Answer (score 0):

The sum is equal to 
$$\left(\frac{1}{1}-\frac{1}{3}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{5}\right)+ \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}\right)+\cdots.$$
Observe the cancellations.

Answer (score 0):

For every $m \ge 2$ we have
\begin{eqnarray}
S_m:&=&\sum_{n=2}^m\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\sum_{n=2}^m\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)\\
&=&\sum_{n=1}^{m-1}\frac{1}{n}-\sum_{n=3}^{m+1}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac12+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+1}\\
&=&\frac32+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m+1}.
\end{eqnarray}
Taking the limit we get
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{2}{n^2-1}=\lim_{m \to \infty}S_m=\frac32.
$$

Comment: I was trying to solve this problem myself and I can get the 3/2 but I was wondering where the 2 on the top goes? Shouldn't the end result of the telescoping be multiplied by the 2?